# Plotting timedelta values gives out of scope axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      commits     commitdates       Age (in days)  Year-Month  server_version  
0         97        2021-04-07       75 days    2021-04          v1       
1         20        2021-05-31       43 days    2021-05          v3       
2         54        2021-06-21       54 days    2021-06          v0.1      
3         100       2021-06-18       75 days    2021-06          v2.1.0       
4         12        2020-12-06       22 days    2020-12           Nan
```

I want to plot the `Age(in days)` which is of type `timedelta64[ns]` , by the number of `commits`  of type `int64` by the `server_versions` on the x axis.

I tried to do this using plotly, but the age values are a bit strange and don't seem correct, I just want them to be displayed starting from 0 to all the rest, like normal int values, I am not sure how can I fix this.
[image]

My code is this:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(final_api, x="Version", y="Age (in days)", color="commits", width =1000, height = 800)
fig.show()
```

I am a bit new to plotly, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to convert your timedelta64 to days and add `days` as suffix for the yaxis, I answer your question based on this random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(pd.timedelta_range(start='1 days', end='75 days'))
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['commits'] = np.random.randint(100, size=len(s))
df['Version'] = 'v'+df['commits'].astype(str)
df['Age (in days)'] = s

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Version", y=df['Age (in days)'].dt.days, color="commits", width =1000, height = 800)
fig.update_yaxes(ticksuffix =  " days")
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]